# Magento 1.9 indexer.php sh: 1: fetch: not found while indexing

Tags: php, shell, magento

I am trying to reindex my data manualy with command line.

I am executing this reindex command from `/var/www/hmtml/shell`

The command I am using is `php ./indexer.php reindexall`

Unfortunately this is not working - the output is a HTML file with folder structure, inputs for commands and some search stuff.

When I am making `php ./indexer.php reindexall > output.html` I am receiving one output, which is: `sh: 1: fetch: not found`

I am using Debian 8.

I've tried `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get update`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh so the strangest thing happened. While doing a pull from my repository, files `my_magento/shell/indexer.php` and `my_magento/shell/abstractp.php` were changes. There was no changes in code whatsoever but the size in bytes has changed.

Couple of days ago I have made deep coppy of my magento shop, so I have coppied my shell folder entirely to my production, and then everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

Correct Magento reindexall command is:

```
php ./indexer.php --reindexall
```

You don't need to output it to a file, if you are running this command in terminal than it should show you output. Try that and flush cache.